# Amavis + Postfix configuration problem

Tags: postfix, spam, amavis, email

Hello we're inherited one server based on Gentoo + Postfix + Amavis-new + Maildrop

```
$ cat /etc/gentoo-release 
Gentoo Base System release 1.12.9
$ equery list
mail-mta/postfix-2.5.5
mail-filter/maildrop-2.0.4
mail-filter/amavisd-new-2.5.2
```

Some config files for postfix+amavis: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9430338/config.tar.gz

Log snipets:

/var/log/mail.log:

```
Oct 15 13:36:29 myhost postgrey: action=pass, reason=triplet found, client_name=mail-yw0-f48.google.com, client_address=209.85.213.48, sender=my@gmail.com, recipient=test@myhost.it
Oct 15 13:36:33 myhost postfix/smtp[3535]: 9D576478A5B: to=<test@myhost.it>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=3.8, delays=0.68/0/0.01/3.1, dsn=2.7.0, status=sent (250 2.7.0 Ok, discarded, id=04288-01 - SPAM)
```

/var/log/amavis.log:

```
Oct 15 13:44:47 myhost.it /usr/sbin/amavisd[4288]: (04288-05) ESMTP::10024 /var/amavis/tmp/amavis-20101015T133629-04288: <my@gmail.com> -> <test@myhost.it> SIZE=2595 Received: from myhost.it ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (myhost.it [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP for <test@myhost.it>; Fri, 15 Oct 2010 13:44:47 +0200 (CEST)
Oct 15 13:44:47 myhost.it /usr/sbin/amavisd[4288]: (04288-05) Checking: I9aGeuG0kC1N [209.85.213.176] <my@gmail.com> -> <test@myhost.it>
Oct 15 13:44:49 myhost.it /usr/sbin/amavisd[4288]: (04288-05) SPAM, <my@gmail.com> -> <test@myhost.it>, Yes, score=1006.929 tag=x tag2=5 kill=10 tests=[AWL=0.390, BAYES_50=0.001, DNS_FROM_OPENWHOIS=1.13, FH_DATE_PAST_20XX=3.188, GTUBE=1000, HTML_MESSAGE=0.001, TVD_SPACE_RATIO=2.219], autolearn=no
Oct 15 13:44:49 myhost.it /usr/sbin/amavisd[4288]: (04288-05) Blocked SPAM, [209.85.213.176] [209.85.213.176] <my@gmail.com> -> <test@myhost.it>, Message-ID: <AANLkTi=UyxaEAOG6+qXQfx+Pbm4if+Hs9BBqyoQHtBR7@mail.gmail.com>, mail_id: I9aGeuG0kC1N, Hits: 1006.929, size: 2595, 2006 ms
```

PROBLEM.

**The problem is that in current configuration the mail system drop all spam message.**

Desired behaviour.

**We would like to receive all messages in the IMAP folder .Junk with ***SPAM*** message prepended to the subject.**

Thank for your time!

Answer (score 1):

What value do you have set for "$final_spam_destiny" (amavisd-new)? It should be D_PASS;

Sorry if it's in your config file, I didn't look at it yet.

Comment: YES you may check in amavisd.conf: $final_spam_destiny = D_PASS;, but still no result. It seems that amavis actually passes the message back to postfix and postfix drops it.